# Determining the coefficient of a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

In a example problem I am trying to solve, it says the right side of the equals sign of the next equation is a Fourier series:
$$
-{1\over EA}\sum_{n = 1}^{n_1}{\cos(n\pi)\over n_1}{\Biggl(c^2{n\pi\over L}P(t) +{L\over n\pi}{d^2P(t)\over dt^2}\Biggl)\sin\biggl({n\pi x\over L} \biggl)}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\Big(c^2w_m^2f_m(t)+{d^2f_m(t)\over dt^2}\Big)\sin(w_mx)
$$

where ${w_m}={{2m-1}\over2L}\pi $.

It also says that the coefficient of that Fourier series can be calculated as:

$$
c^2w_m^2f_m(t) + {d^2f_m(t)\over dt^2} =\\ 
{2\over L}{\sum_{n=1}^{n_1}\int_{0}^L}
\Biggl(\biggl(
{\cos(n\pi)\over n_1}
c^2{n\pi\over L}P(t)+{L\over n\pi}{d^2P(t)\over dt^2}\biggl)
\sin\biggl({n\pi x\over L}\biggl)\sin(w_mx)\Biggl)dx
$$

I do not understand how is the equation above obtained. I know the general sinus form of a Fourier series is:

$$
g(x)=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 
b_k\sin\biggl({k\pi x\over L} \biggl)
$$

Here is what I have tried: I assumed $g(x)$ to be:

$$
g(x)=-{1\over EA}\sum_{n = 1}^{n_1}{\cos(n\pi)\over n_1}{\Biggl(c^2{n\pi\over L}P(t) +{L\over n\pi}{d^2P(t)\over dt^2}\Biggl)\sin\biggl({n\pi x\over L} \biggl)}
$$

and I also assumed that $a_0=0$ and assumed that:

$$
sin\biggl({k\pi x\over L}\biggl)=sin\biggl(w_mx\biggl) 
$$

I also assumed that:

$$
b_k= c^2w_m^2f_m(t) + {d^2f_m(t)\over dt^2}
$$

I tried calculating $b_k$ as:

$$
b_k={2\over L}\int_0^L g(x)sin\biggl({k\pi x\over L}\biggl)
$$

and got:

$$
b_k=\\ -{1\over EA}{2\over L}\sum_{n = 1}^{n_1}\int_0^L{
{\Biggl({\cos(n\pi)\over n_1}}{\biggl(c^2{n\pi\over L}P(t) +{L\over n\pi}{d^2P(t)\over dt^2}\biggl)\sin\biggl({n\pi x\over L} \biggl)}sin(w_mx)\Biggl)}dx 
$$

which means:

$$
c^2w_m^2f_m(t) + {d^2f_m(t)\over dt^2} =\\ -{1\over EA}{2\over L}\sum_{n = 1}^{n_1}\int_0^L{
{\Biggl({\cos(n\pi)\over n_1}}{\biggl(c^2{n\pi\over L}P(t) +{L\over n\pi}{d^2P(t)\over dt^2}\biggl)\sin\biggl({n\pi x\over L} \biggl)}sin(w_mx)\Biggl)}dx 
$$

As you can see, the equation I obtained is not the same as the second equations I have shown in this post. I am trying to understand where did I make a mistake. Here is the source where I found this equation:

[source](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1461348418793122)

I kindly request your help. Thank you in advance.

I wish you a good day.

Comment: Hello, what is the nature of $f_{m}(t)$ in its relation to $P(t)$ - is there any? I'm trying to understand what the subscript on $f$ is enumerating.

Comment: By the way, as a new contributor, this is an example of how to ask a good question.

Comment: Hello Kevin.

There is no relationship between $f_m(t)$ and $P(t)$. They are two separate functions. 

The index $m$ is the series counter of the sum in the first equation of the posted question:

$$
-{1\over EA}\sum_{n = 1}^{n_1}{\cos(n\pi)\over n_1}{\Biggl(c^2{n\pi\over L}P(t) +{L\over n\pi}{d^2P(t)\over dt^2}\Biggl)\sin\biggl({n\pi x\over L} \biggl)}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\Big(c^2w_m^2f_m(t)+{d^2f_m(t)\over dt^2}\Big)\sin(w_mx)
$$

Thank you for your reply. Let me  know if any more information is needed.